# iphone notification results in "unrecognized selector sent to instance..."

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsnotificationcenter

To make it short, I'm registering the following `NSNotification` listener in `ClassA` (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playSong) name:@"playNotification" object:nil];
```

I have the selector declared in `ClassA.h`:

```
- (void)playSong:(NSNotification *) notification;
```

And implementation goes as follows:

```
- (void)playSong:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSString *theTitle = [notification object]; 
    NSLog(@"Play stuff", theTitle);
}
```

In `ClassB` (in the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method) I have:

```
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *stuff = [playlistArray objectAtIndex:row];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"playNotification" object:stuff];
```

It all end up with an error message saying:

> "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

before the `playSong` method is invoked.

Can anybody please help me out here? What am I forgetting when posting a notification from one controller to another?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your `@selector` needs a `:` character if it is to take an argument:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playSong:) name:@"playNotification" object:nil];
```

Instances of `ClassA` do *not* respond to the `playSong` selector, but they *do* respond to the `playSong:` selector.

Comment: Did the trick. Thanks man, such a small detail :-) One last question: If i want to specify which type of object i want the selector to take, what are the syntax to do that? (object:nil) where nil should be the definition.

Comment: @esbenr Sure, you can pass in whatever you like in the `object` parameter.

Comment: In my case, the symptoms were the same, but the cause was the opposite. I had a `:` on my `selector` for a method with no arguments.  In my case, removing the `:` fixed it.