# Background Thread -> update UI

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm downloading and parsing a XML document. During this, I want to update my UIProgressView. I know I have to do this in the main thread, and not in the background thread where the document gets parsed.

But my problem is, when I try this:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgressStr) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", updateTo] waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I send it via a NSString, because a float won't work. But now I get the next error:

```
-[TDFetch setProgressStr]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b9a700
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone notification results in "unrecognized selector sent to instance..."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4523357/iphone-notification-results-in-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) also [iPhone Unrecognized Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284116/iphone-unrecognized-selector)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method you're trying to use takes an argument, that means that it has a colon in the name -- the colon is actually a *part* of the name. You need to include that when you get the selector:

```
@selector(setProgressStr:)
```

Comment: -.-"" I thought I checked for this cause, but then changed the name, and deleted the colon

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot about ':' after name of selector.
Try

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgressStr:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", updateTo] waitUntilDone:NO];
```